# Retrieve data from two lists in office 365 using javascript

Tags: javascript, office-365, master-page, page-layout

I am trying to retrieve data from two different list in SharePoint.
I have created one page layout and ,I already made the code , I checked each function is working fine , but when I use both of them only last one will work, can you please help regarding this :

```
 <div id="NewsContainer" style="width: 100%"></div>
<div id="GeneralMessagesContainer" style="width:100%"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>


            <script type="text/javascript">

                var jq = $.noConflict();
                jq(function () {

                    GetGMMessage();
                    GetUserInfo();
                });

                //$(function () {
                //    GetUserInfo();
                //});
                function GetUserInfo() {
                    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('News');

                    //Start
                    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
                    //END

                    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

                    clientContext.load(collListItem);
                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
                    );
                }
                function GetGMMessage() {
                    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                    var oListGM = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('GeneralMessages');

                    //Start
                    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'FormatMessageDate\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
                    //END

                    this.collListItem = oListGM.getItems(camlQuery);

                    clientContext.load(collListItem);
                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededGM),
                    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedGM)
                    );
                }
                function onQuerySucceededGM(sender, args) {

                    var listItemEnum = collListItem.getEnumerator();

                    //var NewsItemsList = '<thead>' +
                    //'<tr>' +
                    //'</tr>' +
                    //'</thead>';
                    var MessageItemsList = '<div class="News-Item">';
                    while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
                        var oListItemGM = listItemEnum.get_current();
                        MessageItemsList +=
                            '<a class="News-Title" href="/sites/demo/Lists/TestNews/DispForm.aspx?ID='
                            + oListItemGM.get_item('ID') + '">'
                            + oListItemGM.get_item('Title')
                            + '<div class="clear"></div>'
                            + '</a>'
                        ;
                    }
                    MessageItemsList += '</div>';
                    $('#GeneralMessagesContainer').html(MessageItemsList);
                }
                function onQueryFailedGM(sender, args) {
                    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                }
                function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

                    var listItemEnum = collListItem.getEnumerator();


                    var NewsItemsList = '<div class="News-Item">';
                    while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
                        var oListItem = listItemEnum.get_current();
                        var Desc = oListItem.get_item('Summary');
                        Desc = Desc.substring(0,300);
                        NewsItemsList += 
                            '<a class="News-Title" href="/sites/demo/Lists/TestNews/DispForm.aspx?ID='
                            + oListItem.get_item('ID') + '">'
                            + oListItem.get_item('PublishingRollupImage')
                            + oListItem.get_item('Title')
                            + '<p style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal"> Article Date : '
                            + oListItem.get_item('Article_x0020_Date').toISOString().slice(0, 10) + ' , By :'
                            + oListItem.get_item('Posting_x0020_Department') + '</p>'
                            + '<p style="font-size:13px;font-weight:normal">' + Desc + "</p>"
                            + '<div class="clear"></div>'
                            + '</a>'

                        ;
                    }
                    NewsItemsList += '</div>';
                    $('#NewsContainer').html(NewsItemsList);
                }
                function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
                }
            </script>
```

thanks for the answers guys , here is the full updated answer :

```
<div id="GeneralMessagesContainer" style="width:100%"></div>
            <div id="NewsContainer" style="width: 100%"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            var jq = $.noConflict();
            jq(function () {
                GetNewsList();
                GetGMMessage();                   
            });


            function GetNewsList() {
                var clientContextNewsList = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var oList = clientContextNewsList.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('News');

                //Start
                var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
                //END

                this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

                clientContextNewsList.load(collListItem);
                clientContextNewsList.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
                );
            }
            function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

                var listItemEnum = collListItem.getEnumerator();


                var NewsItemsList = '<div class="News-Item">';
                while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItem = listItemEnum.get_current();
                    var Desc = oListItem.get_item('Summary');
                    Desc = Desc.substring(0,300);
                    NewsItemsList +=
                        '<a class="News-Title" href="/sites/demo/Lists/TestNews/DispForm.aspx?ID='
                        + oListItem.get_item('ID') + '">'
                        + oListItem.get_item('PublishingRollupImage')
                        + oListItem.get_item('Title')
                        + '<p style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal"> Article Date : '
                        + oListItem.get_item('Article_x0020_Date').toISOString().slice(0, 10) + ' , By :'
                        + oListItem.get_item('Posting_x0020_Department') + '</p>'
                        + '<p style="font-size:13px;font-weight:normal">' + Desc + "</p>"
                        + '<div class="clear"></div>'
                        + '</a>'

                    ;
                }
                NewsItemsList += '</div>';
                $('#NewsContainer').html(NewsItemsList);
            }
            function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }

            function GetGMMessage() {
                var clientContextGM = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var oListGM = clientContextGM.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('GeneralMessages');

                //Start
                var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'FormatMessageDate\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
                //END

                this.collListItem1 = oListGM.getItems(camlQuery);

                clientContextGM.load(collListItem1);
                clientContextGM.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededGM),
                Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedGM)
                );
            }
            function onQuerySucceededGM(sender, args) {

                var listItemEnum = collListItem1.getEnumerator();

                var MessageItemsList = '<div class="News-Item">';
                while (listItemEnum.moveNext()) {
                    var oListItemGM = listItemEnum.get_current();
                    MessageItemsList +=
                        '<a class="News-Title" href="/sites/demo/Lists/TestNews/DispForm.aspx?ID='
                        + oListItemGM.get_item('ID') + '">'
                        + oListItemGM.get_item('Title')
                        + '<div class="clear"></div>'
                        + '</a>'
                    ;
                }
                MessageItemsList += '</div>';
                $('#GeneralMessagesContainer').html(MessageItemsList);
            }
            function onQueryFailedGM(sender, args) {
                alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give different name to your collection object(**collListItem**) name in both function.

[image]

[image]

in javascript or jQuery first run both function(**GetUserInfo, GetGMMessage**) than run both success function so collection object(**collListItem**) value overwrite by another function value.
so. at last display only last success function value

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<div id="NewsContainer" style="width: 100%"></div>
<div id="GeneralMessagesContainer" style="width:100%"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var jq = $.noConflict();
    jq(function () {

        GetGMMessage();
        GetUserInfo();
    });

    //$(function () {
    //    GetUserInfo();
    //});
    function GetUserInfo() {
        var clientContextUI = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oListUI = clientContextUI.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('News');

        //Start
        var camlQueryUI = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQueryUI.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
        //END

        this.collListItemUI = oListUI.getItems(camlQueryUI);

        clientContext.load(collListItemUI);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );
    }
    function GetGMMessage() {
        var clientContextGM = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oListGM = clientContextGM.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('GeneralMessages');

        //Start
        var camlQueryGM = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQueryGM.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'FormatMessageDate\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
        //END

        this.collListItemGM = oListGM.getItems(camlQueryGM);

        clientContext.load(collListItemGM);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededGM),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailedGM)
        );
    }
    function onQuerySucceededGM(sender, args) {

        var listItemEnumGM = collListItemGM.getEnumerator();

        //var NewsItemsList = '<thead>' +
        //'<tr>' +
        //'</tr>' +
        //'</thead>';
        var MessageItemsList = '<div class="News-Item">';
        while (listItemEnumGM.moveNext()) {
            var oListItemGM = listItemEnumGM.get_current();
            MessageItemsList +=
                '<a class="News-Title" href="/sites/demo/Lists/TestNews/DispForm.aspx?ID='
                + oListItemGM.get_item('ID') + '">'
                + oListItemGM.get_item('Title')
                + '<div class="clear"></div>'
                + '</a>'
            ;
        }
        MessageItemsList += '</div>';
        $('#GeneralMessagesContainer').html(MessageItemsList);
    }
    function onQueryFailedGM(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
    function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

        var listItemEnumUI = collListItemUI.getEnumerator();

        var NewsItemsList = '<div class="News-Item">';
        while (listItemEnumUI.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumUI.get_current();
            var Desc = oListItem.get_item('Summary');
            Desc = Desc.substring(0,300);
            NewsItemsList += 
                '<a class="News-Title" href="/sites/demo/Lists/TestNews/DispForm.aspx?ID='
                + oListItem.get_item('ID') + '">'
                + oListItem.get_item('PublishingRollupImage')
                + oListItem.get_item('Title')
                + '<p style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal"> Article Date : '
                + oListItem.get_item('Article_x0020_Date').toISOString().slice(0, 10) + ' , By :'
                + oListItem.get_item('Posting_x0020_Department') + '</p>'
                + '<p style="font-size:13px;font-weight:normal">' + Desc + "</p>"
                + '<div class="clear"></div>'
                + '</a>'

            ;
        }
        NewsItemsList += '</div>';
        $('#NewsContainer').html(NewsItemsList);
    }
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```